# Put data in implicit intent

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement in android application to show 5 buttons each of them will open the camera intent to allow the user to take a picture. every image is related to a certain information thus each of the images will have a description in the data base and a special id. for example, the first button is to take an image of a car. therefore all images that taken for cars will have id = 1 and a description like "Image of the car .." and so on.

also when the user take the picture I will replace the button with another button to view the image that just has been taken.

Now what i tried to do when the user clicks on the first button I put an extra to the intent with id = 1 and in onActivityResult i'll check if the extra is equal to 1 I will store the image and its id in an hash map. But unfortunately I can't use extras with implicit intent calls.

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use different request_code for intent from all button and based on request_code you can perform action accordingly in onActivityResult .

Comment: Wow I haven't thought of this!! it looks like a great solution! I will try it now and get back to you with my result! appreciate you